# Batch file that removes blank lines and sorts the file (case insensitive) for all encodings

Tags: encoding, batch-file

I would like to make a batch file that removes all blank lines and sorts the lines in the files a regular case-insensitive sort.

So far I got this:

```
@echo off
IF [%1]==[] goto BAR_PAR

IF EXIST %1 (
    egrep -v "^[[:space:]]*$" %1 | sort > xxx
    mv -f xxx %1

) else (
    echo File doesn't exist
)
goto END

:BAR_PAR
echo No Parameter Passed

:END
```

But this screws up my files that have encoding UCS-2 Little Endian.

Is there a way to handle all encoding blindly? 
If not, what should I do to make this UCS-2 Little Endian Compatible?

**UPDATE**
Forgot to mention that I was using Windows but with Cygwin so I have general linux shell commands like grep, sed, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin `sort -f` will sort the file case-insensitively by converting all characters to upper-case.

Cygwin `iconv` converts from one character set to another.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -e '[[:graph:]]' foo.txt | sort -f
```

In short, this command looks for any line that has at least one visible character.  Therefore, lines with only spaces and tabs are excluded.

For some reason, the file I was working with didn't respond to any combination I could think of using '^' and '$'.